# detecting iphone/ipad orientation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

I have this simple script:

```
function orientation() {

  var orientation = window.orientation;
  switch(orientation) {

    case 0:
       alert('0');

         break;

    case 90:
    alert('90');
        break;

    case -90:
    alert('-90');
         break;
  }
}   
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.onorientationchange = orientation();
})
```

but somehow I never get an alert on my ipad when I turn it... Have I made a mistake somewhere?
Thanks for your help guys :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here:

```
window.onorientationchange = orientation;
```

You need to assign the function itself not the result of its execution.